# what does the rows() method do?

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

In the eigen documentation, which is generally pretty good, I see references to a `rows()` method of `MatrixBase`. I am currently trying to find a way to get the number of rows in a matrix without knowing the orientation (Row/Column-major) of the matrix so it would be really convenient to simply call `rows()`.

But I can't find this documented anywhere. What is this method? What does it do? Does it just return `Eigen::Dynamic` for dynamic matrices, or does it know the number of rows?

Looking at [the reference page for MatrixBase](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1MatrixBase.html), I see several mentions of `MatrixBase::rows()` but no link... Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `rows()` method does indeed return the numbers of rows. It is defined in the class `EigenBase`, of which `MatrixBase` is a subclass. Its documentation is at http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/structEigen_1_1EigenBase.html#a5552abd83dbd03c85cea6d61fd8875a5 . One way to find it is to type "rows" in the search field in the upper right of the Eigen documentation and then to click "rows" in the popup that appears; that opens a list of `rows()` methods defined in the library, including `EigenBase::rows()`.

The documentation does not say this explicitly, but the `rows()` method does return the actual number of rows, determined at run-time. The constant `RowsAtCompileTime` returns `Dynamic` for dynamic-size matrices and the number of rows for static-size matrices.

The mentions to `MatrixBase::rows()` in the documentation is a remnant of the past that needs to be eliminated. Thanks for your compliments about the documentation, but we know it can be improved.

Answer (score 1):

Well, `MatrixBase` is derived from `DenseBase` which is in turn derived from `DenseCoeffBase` (with template parameters etc). The row() function is defined there: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/structEigen_1_1EigenBase.html#a5552abd83dbd03c85cea6d61fd8875a5

Doxygen says the function returns "the number of rows.".